# How to turn String to Numeric With Characters in it (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql

I have a field that is a string that I want to turn into Numerics. Problem is that the field can contain characters and it's hard for me to do a simple regular expression replace. Here is an example,

```
field1
1
1.5
2adfk3
2. Section 2
0'#%0ls23
3.987
```

What I essentially want is if the field can be natively casted as a Numeric, then return the Numeric, otherwise return NULL. For example, I want another field, to be

```
field2
1
1.5
NULL
NULL
NULL
3.987
```

where field2 is now a numeric. What is the best way to do this?

In Excel I suppose this would be closest to `IFERROR`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a case expression and a regex:

```
select column1,
       case 
           when column1 ~ '^[0-9\.]+$' then column1::numeric
           else null
       end as column2
from the_table
```

The regex checks if the contents of the column consists only of numbers and a dot. If that is the case, the value can be cast to numeric value, otherwise it returns `null`